# Software as a service

Tags: lightning, quote, order

I have a question about the companies that their products based on Software as a service and subscription. If I don't want to use Salesforce CPQ, what other option to create quotes and orders? How should I define subscription as a product in the Salesforce?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Please take a moment to explore our [tour] and [ask]. Right now, this question isn't defined narrowly enough to fit our format and may be closed. I'd encourage you to [edit] this post to be very specific about your question.

Answer (score 3):

CPQ simply adds an extra layer of features to the objects already present in Salesforce. You can enable Orders, Reduction Orders, and Quotes without CPQ. You'll find them available in the Setup menu under the appropriate menu categories.